# Can someone explain me why apply_filters() is called here?

Tags: plugins

I needed to make a function that is called once on CRUD operations on posts and articles. Then I came on this function: I'm not asking about `purge_zone_once()`, because I've removed the code in that function. I'm asking why does the author use this: `$purge_actions = (array) apply_filters(xx, $yy)` which returns exactly the same `$yy` without touching it:

```
function register_purge_actions() {

    // use `my_plugin_purge_actions` filter to alter default purge actions
    $purge_actions = (array) apply_filters(
        'my_plugin_purge_actions',
        array(
            'publish_phone', 'save_post', 'edit_post', 'delete_post',
            'wp_trash_post', 'clean_post_cache',
            'trackback_post', 'pingback_post', 'comment_post',
            'edit_comment', 'delete_comment', 'wp_set_comment_status',
            'switch_theme', 'wp_update_nav_menu', 'edit_user_profile_update'
        )
    );

    foreach ($purge_actions as $action) {
        if ( did_action( $action ) ) {
            purge_zone_once();
        } else {
            add_action( $action, array( $this, 'purge_zone_once' ) );
        }
    }
}
function purge_zone_once() {
    //blabla
}
```

I dont know how (and why) it "alters default purge actions" - like it's written in the comment. My own code works without the code `apply_filters()` at the beginning.

I dont understand the point of the code `apply_filters()` at the beginning, which returns the same array (!).

This is the nginx cache purge plugin, which seems well coded, so I guess there's something important here but I dont see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not doing anything *on its own* - the original author is offering you the ability to change these hard-coded actions without needing to edit the source code itself.

Imagine you just edited the array right there. Then a plugin update comes along, the file is overwritten, and your custom changes are lost.

Using a filter, the original author has allowed you to "plug" into their code from elsewhere, and now the two can co-exist without you losing your changes anytime the original plugin gets an update.

In fact, whether a plugin is actually ever updated or not (perhaps it's a private plugin and not hosted on the WordPress plugin repo), it's good practice to utilise filters & actions - it's the very heart of WordPress' "pluggable" architecture.

It seems like you've found this code online and are repurposing it to use directly yourself? In which case I can see why the filter could appear redundant, but I hope my answer sheds some light on why you might often see filters & actions in the wild.

**Update:** Using the above code as an example, you could (from your own plugin or theme) add an additional action to `$purge_actions` like so:

```php
add_filter( 'my_plugin_purge_actions', function ( $actions ) {
    $actions[] = 'my_custom_action';

    return $actions;
});
```

Learn more about [WordPress hooks](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/).

Comment: Ok I can see... but how to "plug" into this architecture? May I ask you to add just a few lines of a sample which "plugs" into this architecture? I feel like it's related to `my_plugin_purge_actions`?

Comment: @OlivierPons I have added an example.